# Feeds don't expire

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed

When I try to load a feed using Miranda RSSNews plugin, it only loads on startup.

The root of the problem seems to be in the server-side cache which does not seem to grace `If-Modified-Since` when using `Accept-Encoding: gzip`:

```
GET /feeds/tag?tagnames=oracle+or+sql+or+rdbms+or+dbms+or+database+or+mysql+or+postgresql+or+tsql+or+sql-server HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1) RSSNews plugin for Miranda IM
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 11 Apr 2011 15:09:39 GMT
A-IM: feed
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: stackoverflow.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Expires: Mon, 11 Apr 2011 15:14:39 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Apr 2011 15:09:39 GMT
Vary: *
Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2011 17:04:37 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Compare to:

```
GET /feeds/tag?tagnames=oracle+or+sql+or+rdbms+or+dbms+or+database+or+mysql+or+postgresql+or+tsql+or+sql-server HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1) RSSNews plugin for Miranda IM
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 11 Apr 2011 15:09:39 GMT
A-IM: feed
Host: stackoverflow.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 11 Apr 2011 17:20:18 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Apr 2011 17:15:18 GMT
Vary: *
Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2011 17:23:16 GMT
Content-Length: 72163
```

**Update:**

Seems that the feeds don't expire for too long even without the `gzip` encoding. Just run this:

```
GET /feeds/tag?tagnames=oracle+or+sql+or+rdbms+or+dbms+or+database+or+mysql+or+postgresql+or+tsql+or+sql-server&sort=newest HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1) RSSNews plugin for Miranda IM
A-IM: feed
Host: stackoverflow.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 13 Apr 2011 15:24:30 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Apr 2011 15:19:30 GMT
Vary: *
Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2011 21:28:42 GMT
Content-Length: 78697
Connection: keep-alive
```

It returns the feed as of `Wed, 13 Apr 2011 15:19:30 GMT` despite the fact it was requested 6 hours later and the expiration time was only 5 minutes.

Comment: investigating...

Comment: After investigation I believed this was fix, but apparently not. Very odd: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6546444/23354

Comment: It wasn't fixed. It will be next deploy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a bug in our output-cache provider, so it used *sliding* instead of *absolute* expiry. So it was only when the readers stopped hitting it that it would expire.

Fixed next deploy.

Comment: Trusting you on this one!

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be fixed by now.

Comment: You sure about that?

Comment: @Narsil: my reader has no more than `5` minutes delay now.

Comment: Interesting; I couldn't see any obvious cause here (or, indeed, repro); I've just come back to re-investigate, so I'm intrigued that it has gone away. I wonder if this was a dodgy intermediary caching something incorrectly?

Comment: @Marc: probably. Actually, I tried this from two separate `IP` addresses and it seemed that two different versions of the cache were returned (though on they day I asked they both did not expire on time). Now, the feeds seem to expire properly from both `IP` addesses (and I switched to `StackGuru` anyway as suggested by Jeff here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87575/questions-response-time-and-publish-subcsribe-notification).

Comment: Actually, it wasn't fixed. But it will be next deploy.