# What's wrong with RSS Feed?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, feed

This is something new. I was using an RSS reader that checked questions for some tags every minute. It was working fine till recently. But now sometimes there are questions asked 1 hour ago but I don't get the feed. Even after I see the question in webpage and request feed, it just doesn't appear. I refresh feeds with Google Reader and Feed notifier at the same time, Google Reader gets something new but Feed Notifier doesn't. Is there some kind of request restriction for RSS feeds? Maybe based on IP? Or is the problem about readers?

This request was taken a few minutes ago:

```
GET /feeds/tag?tagnames=asp.net-mvc&sort=newest HTTP/1.1
A-Im: feed
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Accept: application/atom+xml,application/rdf+xml,application/rss+xml,application/x-netcdf,application/xml;q=0.9,text/xml;q=0.2,*/*;q=0.1
User-Agent: FeedNotifier/2.2 +http://www.feednotifier.com/
Host: stackoverflow.com
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 14 Apr 2011 11:14:59 GMT
```

Comment: Could you mention which RSS Reader?

Comment: Feed Notifier and Google Reader. They are both "late"

Comment: Could this be related to [Feeds don't expire when requested with gzip encoding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86991/feeds-dont-expire-when-requested-with-gzip-encoding)? Any chance you can sniff into the readers request to see if it sends `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` or something similar?

Comment: So, any news on the `Accept-Encoding` sent by your reader?

Comment: The problem seems to be more complex. Gzipped and uncompressed feeds seem to be cached separately but they both don't expire on time.

Comment: We have seen this, and I am investigating. I was under the impression (from the linked thread) that it had evaporated, but obviously not.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Any update on this? I'm seeing this issue as well.

Comment: @FogleBird really? this just refuses to die, eh? After investigation I was under the impression that this was fixed. I'll revisit it.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Right now, this feed is out of date for me, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/python

Comment: @FogleBird - it is... curious; more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6546444/23354

Comment: Fixed next deploy

Comment: Isn't hitting an RSS feed once a minute rather bad RSS etiquette? I thought most consumers of RSS limited themselves to once an hour (or so) to keep from overloading the RSS provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a bug in our output-cache provider, so it used *sliding* instead of *absolute* expiry. So it was only when the readers stopped hitting it that it would expire.

Fixed next deploy.

Comment: I haven't been using RSS feed for a long time but I tried it today since you said it was fixed. I don't know if it's the reader (Feed Notifier) or some other thing but it's still there.

Comment: @Narsil - which "it"...? can you be specific about symptoms? sorry if this seems redundant, but I want to be sure it is the *same* thing, vs something crazy similar-sounding...

Comment: I see some question is posted from [StackGuru](http://stackapps.com/questions/345/stackguru-a-near-realtime-bot-for-all-stackexchange-sites) but I don't get anything from RSS feed.

Comment: @Narsil - which feed; can you give your feed url?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=asp.net-mvc%2basp.net-mvc-3&sort=newest For example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732047/how-to-make-a-table-cell-clickable-with-an-ajax-actionlink) doesn't show up in that feed

Comment: @Narsil indeed it doesn't, but the feed is up to date; `<updated>2011-07-18T11:51:48Z</updated>` - so: if there is a bug, it is different. I will investigate, but that is not the same thing.

Comment: @Narsil - that feed is "1st tag **AND** 2nd tag"; the post you cite only has 1 of the tags; you probably mean "1st tag **OR** 2nd tag", i.e. [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=asp.net-mvc+or+asp.net-mvc-3&sort=newest)

Comment: The problem is in the feed URL. I don't know where I got it from but it only shows questions tagged with asp.net-mvc and asp.net-mvc3 both. The question is displayed in only asp.net-mvc-3 tag feed.

Comment: @Marc you are right. I will keep checking it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very old. However, I had the same *problem*.

I added the [*Recent C# questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/?tagnames=c%23&sort=newest) feed to *Feed Notifier* and set the refresh interval to 30 seconds. I refreshed the appropriate webpage accordingly in order to see, if it works. Guess what, new posts were late in *Feed Notifier*! But I've looked into the feed with my browser, and it seems to me, that feed data provided by SO is updated only every 5 minutes.

Comment: You may want to ask a new question about this